# Using svn with xampp for php projects

Tags: svn, xampp, configure

I have heard a lot about version control and would like to work on it. I read some tutorials about the same. However i am not quite sure how svn works with xampp.
I have installed svn, Tortoise svn and made the necessary changes in xampp. For instance i copied the two required modules to c:/xampp/apache/modules and also made changes to the conf file in apache. Here are the changes made in c:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.

```
# Configure Subversion repository
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNPath C:\svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName “Subversion repository”
AuthUserFile c:\svn_conf\passwd
Require valid-user
</Location>t
```

I created the repository at **c:/svn** and also created the password file. However when i visit **http:/localhost/svn** i get a 404 page not found error. Where am i going wrong. what am i missing.? Any pointers?? Thanks in advance.

- edit:

  **i tried a little harder. changed the settings in httpd.conf files which are as above. But now i get the 500 error.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best guide for what you want is here:
http://noobcode.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/what-is-subversion-as-quoted-by.html

I´ve googled all day...

Answer (score 1):

this should help
http://serk01.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/how-to-create-your-own-home-svn-repository-with-xamppapache/

Comment: thanks. I have used the same link and followed the steps. Since i could not get what the tuts says i raised a question here. If you notice i have put a comment there as well..

Comment: if you are getting 500 error means, the entry in the httpd.conf is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in this entry,
SVNPath C:\svn                           should be       SVNPath "C:\svn"
AuthType Basic                           should be       AuthType "Basic"
AuthName “Subversion repository”         should be       AuthName "Subversion repository"
AuthUserFile c:\svn_conf\passwd          should be       AuthUserFile  "c:\svn_conf\your_file_name_in_svn_conf"

Regards
Hashim Ikram
hashim.ikram@anchorstech.com